# Getting the result of multiple function calls in a single result window

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to have the result of the "main query" as many times as there are identifiers in the result of the first query and have them following each other like in the second and the third window of result in a single result set.

[image]
Is it possible to get this result in a single query ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

**EDIT** : *text version of the queries*

```
-- List of all identifiers to pass to the function (GetGrappageParLien531)
select id_personne_groupe from t_groupe where idgroupe > 0

-- "Main query"
select
case grap.niveau when 0 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col1,
case grap.niveau when 1 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col2,
case grap.niveau when 2 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col3,
pm.SIREN
from GetGrappageParLien531(23) grap
join t_personne p on grap.Pers_filiale = p.idpersonne
join t_personne_morale pm on pm.idpersonne = p.idpersonne

select
case grap.niveau when 0 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col1,
case grap.niveau when 1 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col2,
case grap.niveau when 2 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col3,
pm.SIREN
from GetGrappageParLien531(25) grap
join t_personne p on grap.Pers_filiale = p.idpersonne
join t_personne_morale pm on pm.idpersonne = p.idpersonne
```

*The result of the first query returns multiple identifiers (int), the result of the two next queries always and only have the col1 column filled then few lines with the col2 column filled, it describes a hierarchy*

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Besides, I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: With a stored procedure it is relatively easy strate forword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cross apply` solution is probably not the worst idea. Perhaps you can try this:

```
select id_personne_groupe,
        case grap.niveau when 0 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col1,
        case grap.niveau when 1 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col2,
        case grap.niveau when 2 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col3,
        pm.SIREN 
from t_groupe CROSS APPLY
        GetGrappageParLien531(t_group.id_personne_groupe) grap
        join t_personne p on grap.Pers_filiale = p.idpersonne
        join t_personne_morale pm on pm.idpersonne = p.idpersonne
where t_groupe.idgroupe > 0
```

This should evaluate the "main query" for every result from `select id_personne_groupe from t_groupe where idgroupe > 0`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `cross apply`

```
select
    case grap.niveau when 0 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col1,
    case grap.niveau when 1 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col2,
    case grap.niveau when 2 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col3,
    pm.SIREN
from (values(23), (25)) t(a)
cross apply GetGrappageParLien531(t.a) grap
join t_personne p on grap.Pers_filiale = p.idpersonne
join t_personne_morale pm on pm.idpersonne = p.idpersonne
```

Comment: This would only produce one result set, which is not what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your first query to create a CURSOR, and then execute your "Main" query for each iteration of the CURSOR.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to cycle through `id_personne_groupe` and to correctly filter is by using the function `GetGrappageParLien531`, you can use this cursor:

```
DECLARE @id_personne_groupe INT

DECLARE PersonneGroupeCursor CURSOR FOR
    select id_personne_groupe from t_groupe where idgroupe > 0

OPEN PersonneGroupeCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM PersonneGroupeCursor INTO @id_personne_groupe

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- "Main query"
    select
    case grap.niveau when 0 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col1,
    case grap.niveau when 1 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col2,
    case grap.niveau when 2 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col3,
    pm.SIREN
    from GetGrappageParLien531(@id_personne_groupe) grap
    join t_personne p on grap.Pers_filiale = p.idpersonne
    join t_personne_morale pm on pm.idpersonne = p.idpersonne

    select
    case grap.niveau when 0 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col1,
    case grap.niveau when 1 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col2,
    case grap.niveau when 2 Then p.identifiantuniversel + ' - ' + Isnull(pm.SIREN,'(pas de siren)') + ' - ' + pm.raisonsociale else '' end as col3,
    pm.SIREN
    from GetGrappageParLien531(@id_personne_groupe) grap
    join t_personne p on grap.Pers_filiale = p.idpersonne
    join t_personne_morale pm on pm.idpersonne = p.idpersonne

    FETCH NEXT FROM PersonneGroupeCursor INTO @id_personne_groupe

END

CLOSE PersonneGroupeCursor
DEALLOCATE PersonneGroupeCursor
```